# Cannot create an object of class SVM in Scheduler task

Tags: scheduled-tasks, typo3, scheduler

I have a TYPO3 extension providing a scheduler task (extension *scheduler* 6.2.0).
In this task I have following strage problem:

```
private $svm;
...
$this->svm = new \SVM();
```

When this line is executed during task execution (started from cron job) program hangs up and does nothing. No exception, no error. It is just waiting for something.
If this line is executed within extension - an object is created.
If I start *scheduler* task manually in TYPO3 back-end - an object is also created.

It looks like during CLI execution class *SVM* is unknown. But then there should be an error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the class `SVM`is unknown, an error would occur and nothing would wait. I propose that you debug that and check, e.g. with `class_exists($this->svm)` if this class exists.

Without knowing more it is hard to help more.

Comment: OK. Function call `class_exists(\SVM::class)` gives _TRUE_ back if called within extension. It gives _FALSE_ back if called within _scheduler_ task.   

To tell you the truth I don't know what info could be useful at this point.

Comment: How does the require_once looks?

Comment: The same thing occurs for `extension_loaded('svm')` - within extension it is _TRUE_, called from task - _FALSE_.
`require_once` needs a path and _svm_ is php extension. What path should I enter for extension?

Comment: In _php.ini_ I have found **extension=svm.so**, so it should be loaded...

Comment: There is a custom php.ini for the cli context. I am pretty sure it is not added there

Comment: YEAH!!!!!!!!!!! That was it!!!!!!!!!! In `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` **svm.so** was not activated. Since it is only in _root_ access,  I've used `php -dextension=svm.so ...` to load extension dynamically.